# How to calculate a formula and get a floating point number

Tags: ruby, floating-point

How do I perform some math using this formula? If `number` is `37`, I'd expect it to end up with `133.2`.

```
number / 100 * 360
```

Comment: Did `= number / 100 * 360` work? BTW `37 / 100 * 360` evals to `0`, because `/` on integers return an integer.

Comment: Correct. I get 0. So how do I get .37 when I do 37 / 100 is the question I guess.

Comment: `number.to_f / 100 * 360` should work (`1.to_f` returns `1.0` in float).

Comment: @Jokester You should post that as answer. :) It's correctamundo.

Comment: It's ok. BTW posting actual and expected result makes it easier to find real question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the numbers to be multiplied/divided/added/subtracted if a float, then the result will be a float. If `number` is divided by a float, then the result would be a float, and multiplication on that would be a float.

```
number = 37
number / 100.0 * 360 # => 133.2
```

Comment: Nop. `37/100` are evaled first.

Comment: @Jokester You pointed that out at almost the same time as I was correcting it. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

```
number = 37
p number.to_f / 100 * 360   #=> 133.2
p number * 1.0 / 100 * 360  #=> 133.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Numeric#fdiv`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Numeric.html#method-i-fdiv):

```
number = 37
number.fdiv(100)        #=> 0.37
number.fdiv(100) * 360  #=> 133.2
```